# How to update NetworkImage widget in the UI instant after taking and uploading image to the Firebase Storage and retrieving it at the same time?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

Following is my code. I'm trying to upload get image and upload it to firebase storage.

```
              IconButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            XFile? image = await _imagePicker.pickImage(
                                source: ImageSource.camera);

                            if (image != null) {
                              _firebaseStorageStorage.uploadImage(
                                  imageName: image.name + user!.id,
                                  filePath: image.path);
                              Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _imageURLController =
                                      _firebaseStorageStorage
                                          .getDownloadURL();
                                });
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.add_a_photo_sharp,

                            // color: Color(0xffc4b5e0),
                          )),
```

and here is the code for .uploadImage method.

```
class FirebaseStorageStorage {
  final Reference referenceRoot = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
  late final Reference imagesRef;
  late Reference _imageToUpload;
  String _downloadURL = '';

  void uploadImage(
      {required String imageName, required String filePath}) async {
    imagesRef = referenceRoot.child("images");
    _imageToUpload = imagesRef.child(imageName);
    UploadTask uploadTask = _imageToUpload.putFile(File(filePath));
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
    //await _imageToUpload.putFile(File(filePath));
    await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) async {
      _downloadURL = url;
    });
    //_downloadURL= await _imageToUpload.getDownloadURL();
  }

  String getDownloadURL() {
    return _downloadURL;
  }
}
```

Now here is where I load and use the image from the firebase firestore.

```
CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 60,
                            child: _imageURLController == ''
                                ? const Icon(
                                    size: 100,
                                    Icons.person,
                                    color: Color(0xffc5daf2),
                                  )
                                : Image.network(
                                    _imageURLController,
                                    loadingBuilder:
                                        (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                                      if (loadingProgress == null) {
                                        return CircleAvatar(
                                          radius: 60,
                                          foregroundImage:
                                              NetworkImage(_imageURLController),
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        return const Center(
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    },
                                  )),
```

I even tried Future.delayed in the first block of code cause I'm trying to set the  _imageURLController to the latest imageURL. Now this still doesn't work, any help or advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `await` on `uploadImage()` to wait for the image to be uploaded first, that way you don't have to use `Future.delayed()`. You can just do the following:

```
String uploadImage({required String imageName, required String filePath}) async {
    imagesRef = referenceRoot.child("images");
    _imageToUpload = imagesRef.child(imageName);
    UploadTask uploadTask = _imageToUpload.putFile(File(filePath));
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
    return await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }
```

Then to update the state, try the following:

```
IconButton(
 onPressed: () async {
 XFile? image = await _imagePicker.pickImage(
 source: ImageSource.camera);

  if (image != null) {
  String url = await  _firebaseStorageStorage.uploadImage(
 imageName: image.name + user!.id,
 filePath: image.path);
 setState(() {
   _imageURLController = url;
   });
  }
},
```